# Android : Facebook like newsfeed with multiple images and videos

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, feed

In my android application i need to create a need feed like in facebook. In Facebook if there is multiple videos or images in single post or newsfeed then initially all will not display,instead of that a faded column will appear after 5 or more items and will say "+4" and when we click on the post a new feed will display which will display all items in that feed.Below i have shown an images exactly like this.
[image] 
How to do that?please help me.

Comment: Share your code u have written up to now

Comment: @finki I haven't done this.What i know is to create a recyclerview with multiple views inside it where i can display single image or single video with text or even both.I just wanted to know how to incoperate above like structure with a listview or recyclerview.

Comment: Your research skills doens't seem really high ;) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout

Comment: @finki i don't think gridlayout can be used here.I am planing to build a facebook like news feed inside my app.You can see in facebook we can scroll down to see each feeds in our timeline where most of them with a single video or image, but in some case there may be multiple images/videos in a single post like the above picture and its dynamic also.

Comment: You need to make a custom adapter of course. But I would use it at a basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for showing multiple images and videos

- https://abhilunagaria.blogspot.com/2016/06/best-way-to-display-multiple-image-grid_8.html

Use Staggered Recyclerview for this type of list check the below examples

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager
- https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html
- https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html

Comment: i want to show multiple items in a single view of a recyclerview. From ur example what i understood is that staggered gridlayout is used to align recyclerview items without any orientations, its not about showing multiple items in a single view.

Comment: @KJEjava48 check the first example

Comment: that looks something useful.Let me check that.

Comment: @KJEjava48 if you found useful please don't forget to up vote

Answer (score 0):

try bitFrames  https://github.com/deepaktwr/BitFrames

Description
ViewFrame takes set of image links (local or network based) and will frame them based on their dimensions.The container may contain 1, 2, 3 or max 4 images and they will occupy space based on their dimensions.The image count with greater than 4 will show the overflow number.

Comment: Now, this library has an issue with Kotlin (Data binding). I try and can't use it for my project.

Comment: Data binding issue was reported and was solved in the latest version.